# Implement a color lookup SQL table based on value ranges

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to implement a SQL table that stores lower limit , higher limit, and color. then define different ranges for a particular color.

The intention is to lookup if a value falls between certain range and then decide the color.

how to implement this without having any gaps in value range?

Comment: add some code of what you have tried...

Answer (score 0):

There are not to many details about requirements and Your implementation but I guess You can use following idea:

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ColorRanges](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RangeFrom] [int] NULL,
    [RangeTo] [int] NULL,
    [Color] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ColorRanges] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO [ColorRanges] (RangeFrom, RangeTo, Color)
VALUES (NULL, 0, 'Green'),
       (0, 100, 'Yellow'),
       (100, 200, 'Orange'),
       (200, NULL, 'Red')
```

The assumption is that there might be infinte ranges - range value wound be `NULL`.

2nd assumption is there might be overlapping ranges - You can easily adjust it if Your requirements are different.

Then selecting color for specified value is:

```
DECLARE @Value int
SET @Value = 100

SELECT Color 
FROM ColorRanges
WHERE (RangeFrom IS NULL AND RangeTo IS NULL) OR  -- that scenario might be not valid
      (RangeFrom IS NULL AND @Value <= RangeTo) OR
      (@Value BETWEEN RangeFrom AND RangeTo) OR
      (@Value >= RangeFrom AND RangeTo IS NULL)
```